# What is the form ID of a submitted Webform to perform a custom redirect?

Tags: 7, webforms

Once the webform is submitted, I need it to be redirected to edit form page where user can edit that form again.

I know is at `webform->components->form` settings and choose custom redirect. What is the value I should key in (since form ID is always different)?

Answer (score 3):

There are number of ways to do this:

1. Use rules on event "After saving a node" -> condition : "node is of type webform" -> action : "add redirect" ; path : `node/[nid]/webform`. **Note:** `[nid]` might not be the exact token, but you'll get the exact token in the replacement patterns in the Rules UI.
2. Implement `hook_node_insert` in your custom module which triggers after every new node is created, check for the `$node->type` if it is of type `webform`, and use `drupal_goto` to redirect to the form components page. Path `node/{$node->id}/webform`.
3. Alter the `node_form` for webform to add a submit handler and use
   `form_state['redirect'] = 'node' . $form_state['nid'] . '/webform';`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to go to the `Webform settings configuration` page i.e `www.example.com/node/[nid]/webform/configure`.

There under the `Redirection location` settings, you can add the Custom URL with the required tokens i.e `node/[node:nid]/submission/[submission:sid]/edit`.

Please make sure that [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module is installed and the permissions allow the user to edit the submission.

Answer (score 0):

I use webform rule to solve my issue. Just need to install webform rule module.